# Software RAID 5 with Multiple Partitions (one encrypted partition)

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, raid-5

Can I have multiple partitions using Software RAID 5 on an Ubuntu Server?

For example, say using a 4 drive RAID 5 setup, I want one massive partition for storage and a second smaller but encrypted partition. I also need this to be able expandable (I believe you can do that with grow but not sure if multiple partitions effects this).

Is this all available with LVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all of this is possible with LVM...some of it without.  mdadm can create the raid virtualdisk.  the virtualdisk can house any partition type (lvm).  the lvm virtualdisk can house any partition type (luks).  the automagic mounting may prove more difficult, but it's doable

Comment: aking1012, any chance you'd be willing to walk me through the simplest logical layout of different drive layers. I'm thinking its raw HDDs, LVM, mdadm virtual disks, partitions? Did I add an extra layer I don't need?

Comment: I thought we did that already? raw HDDs => mdadm(the raid manager) => lvm(there's a couple parts here) => partitions(really just format creating them is done with lvm)