# Adding Space to RAID5 using mdadm, lvm and ext3

Tags: lvm, ext3, raid-5, mdadm

I have seen a few descriptions about using mdadm with lvm to create an easily expandable raid, such as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/215797/software-raid-5-with-multiple-partitions-one-encrypted-partition), but I still think I'm missing something. Say that I create the raid using mdadm with 4 drives using raid5, then make an lvm volume(?) on top of that, then format that lvm volume with ext3. That all sounds good.

Then I want to add some more space, so I put another hard drive in. How do I add it? If I just add it to the lvm, then it is not part of the raid5 set. If I add it using "mdadm --grow", then after that is done, I still have to unmount and resize the ext3 filesystem.

I thought if I used lvm on top of mdadm it would be unnecessary to unmount and wait for the resize (which takes forever with a 5tb raid). Is that correct?

I have done this before without using lvm, using just "mdadm --grow", then I think resize2fs. But that took days, during which the drive had to be unmounted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ext3 supports online resizing, which means that you can grow the filesystem while it is mounted. The procedure would be:

1. Add the new drive
2. `mdadm --grow` to add it to the RAID
3. `pvresize` to increase the size of the PV
4. `lvextend` to increase the size of the LV
5. `resize2fs` to grow the filesystem

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so my next question would be; what's the point in me using lvm then, if ext3 supports online resizing by itself?

Comment: LVM gives you flexibility regarding how you organise the storage. It allows you to use multiple PVs in a single LV (e.g. you add another RAID set), and have multiple LVs per PV (e.g. you want more than one filesystem). It's usually a good idea to setup LVM even if you only have one PV and one LV initially.